# Ionic 3 Android device back button is exiting the app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins, back-button

On clicking of Android Back button, app is exiting. I am trying to handle it via `registerBackButtonAction` but it is not getting called itself. If I use the blank ionic app without any cordova plugins, its working fine and I can listen to `registerBackButtonAction`. I am suspecting the some cordova plugin is getting conflict with Android Back button. Here are the list of plugins I am using, any help would be appreciated.

```
"plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
  "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {},
  "cordova-plugin-file": {},
  "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
  "cordova-plugin-streaming-media": {},
  "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
  "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
  "call-number": {},
  "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
  },
  "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-audio-recorder": {},
  "cordova-plugin-network-information": {}
},
"platforms": [
  "android"
]
```

Comment: i am using the workaround for now with `document.addEventListener("backbutton",fn,false)`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app.component.ts
and add this code

```
platformReady(){         // back button functionality.
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        this.statusBar.styleDefault();

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.splashScreen.hide();
        }, 100);
        this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>this.myHandlerFunction());
    });
}

myHandlerFunction(){
    let nav = this.app._appRoot._getActivePortal() || this.app.getActiveNav();
    let activeView = nav.getActive();

    if (activeView != null) {
      if (nav.canGoBack()) {
            nav.pop();
      } else if(activeView.isOverlay) {
            activeView.dismiss();
      } else {
           this.showExitAlert();
      }
    }
 }


 showExitAlert() {
    this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'app name',
    cssClass:'alert-danger',
    message: 'Are you sure you want to exit the app?',
    enableBackdropDismiss: false,
    buttons: [{ text: 'Yes', handler: () => {
                this.platform.exitApp();
            }
        }, { text: 'Cancel', role: 'cancel', handler: () => {

           } 
        }]
    }).present();
}
```